# How to bind custom HtmlHelper to controller's action parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, model-binding

I created my own ASP.NET MVC CheckBoxList HtmlHelper based on examples I searched on the net. The Helper basically creates multiple checkbox inputs on the page:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Item1" value="1" checked>Item1</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item2" value="2" >Item2</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item3" value="3" >Item3</input>
```

Can someone give me an idea on how the HtmlHelpers bind the form control values back to the Action Parameters, and for my CheckBoxList above, how do I bind the values back to the Action Parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, they don't.

The HtmlHelper methods simply assist in generating Html.

It is the job of ModelBinders (by default `DefaultModelBinder`) and various value providers to read the incoming form, querystring etc. parameters and bind them to your action parameters.